# Show the next tag badge on the main site profile too

Tags: support, profile-page

On the activity tab on your profile on meta, it shows you the next tag badge that you'll earn - mine says it's a bronze [discussion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) badge.

Why not do this on the main site, too? That way I won't have to go count how many [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) answers I have, and what the score is, etc. It would just be there, on my profile.

Comment: FYI, when you choose to track a tag badge, your progress towards that badge becomes visible to **all site users** (although the popup window where you can see progress towards *all* your badges is visible only to yourself).

Comment: @randal'thor fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You *can* already do this.

The only reason it doesn't come up automatically is because you don't yet have all the rep-based privileges. I'll show you how to do this based on screenshots from my account on a site where *I* don't have all the privileges.

First, go to the box in the top left of your Activity page and click the little wheel to change from tracking a privilege to tracking a tag badge:

[image]

Once you've set it to track a tag badge instead of a privilege, you can then choose *which* tag badge to track by clicking the other little wheel on the left:

[image]

You'll then get a popup window with all the possible tag badges you can track. Have fun!